# Warning: Module "openssl" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Tags: laravel, powershell, visual-studio-2010, windows-10, laravel-10

When I write PHP artisan serve in Laravel 10,
This error always write in console. How to resolve this issue?

PS C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\test_proj> **php artisan serve**

> *PHP Warning:  Module "openssl" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Module "openssl" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>
> WARN  PHP Warning: Module "openssl" is already loaded in Unknown on
> line 0.*

Answer (score 0):

Check both the `php.ini` file used by your web server (like Apache or Nginx) and the one used by `PHP CLI`. These files are often located in the PHP installation directory or a separate conf directory.
Look for lines that include `extension=openssl.so` (on Linux) or `extension=php_openssl.dll` (on Windows). Ensure that these lines are not duplicated in either file.

You need to find all relevant `php.ini` files in your `xampp` directory and remove or comment out one of the module directives like this:

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

After a server restart, this should solve it.